# AutoSize DataGridView in Vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

How can the table be auto fitted in the DataGridView using VB.NET ? The operations like AutoSizeColumn and AutoSizeRows are only for the data inside the table. I want to fit the table inside the Viewbox in such a manner that no extra space will left.

Comment: The AutoResize methods act on the DataGridView - its rows and columns - rows and columns *based on* the nature of the data in the DataTable.  It is not clear what you are asking, nor what "the Viewbox" refers to,

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to calculate and set the row heights/column widths yourself, based on the height/width of the `DataGridView`.

This is most often (and most effectively) done in the `Resize` event handler.